# Display the last few lines of a very large file

Tags: linux

I've got a log file that's managed to bloat upto 150MB. Is there a way to read only the last say 100 lines of the file instead of the whole thing? I don't want to have to download a 150 MB file with my current connection. I'd rather SSH in and read the relevant parts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tail [filename]`

Answer (score 5):

To expand on Farseeker's answer: `tail -n 100 [filename]` to get the last 100 lines.

Comment: Or: `tail -100 foo`

Comment: the -f option shows the last five, and then each new line as it comes in. You can also do things like -100f for the last 100 lines, then follow, and you can grep the output, just put "| grep ERROR" after any of these, and you will only see lines with ERROR in them